# Laravel - Dúvida sobre @foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
@foreach($listaProdutos as $key => $listaProduto)  
     @if(...)   
         ...
     @endif
@endforeach
```

Existe algum comando ou forma de pular para o próximo registro de `$listaProduto` se a condição `@if` for satisfeita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem sim, o `@continue`

```
@foreach($listaProdutos as $key => $listaProduto)  
     @if(...)   
         @continue
     @endif
@endforeach
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

---

- [Blade Templates - Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)
- [How to break a foreach loop in laravel blade view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189524/how-to-break-a-foreach-loop-in-laravel-blade-view)